# cannot delete file with strange character

Tags: file-system

I am using JellyBean 4.1.2. There is a directory with a file that is with stange character. I use many app to delete it but did not success. And I use shell to look at it. When I issue ls command. it show lstat './as`a.5r' failed: No such file or directory. How can I delete this file

Comment: Yes, but I cannot delete in windows too.

Comment: Can you rename the file?

Answer (score 1):

I installed a terminal emulator app on my Android smartphone ([Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm), which is [open source](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator)) then I used it to change directory (`cd`) to where the file was and removed the file (`rm`).

You don't need to type the entire file name, you can use the terminal auto completion. On a Linux desktop, you could start typing  `rm file_n` and hit the **Tab** key so the terminal would complete the command: `rm file_n@me`. On that emulator app, to emulate the desktop's **Tab** key, hit the **Volume up button** then type `t` with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Google how to get short names for files using bash, and use that short file name with rm to delete the file using a terminal emulator. same for Windows too

Answer (score -2):

If your mobile allows to reboot into safe mode then enter safe mode and try deleting. 
Otherwise only way is take a backup of the required content, format the memory then restore. Hope this helps..